# how to upload video using Facebook sdk 7.3 in unity?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

I've tried building apps with Xcode and it has been a struggle, i then discovered unity and an entire world opened up to me. and then i released 3 games this year on the iOS apple store made in unity.

now I'm trying to build a game and this games main feature is to upload and view videos. let me call it what it is making an app with unity. why? because i know how to use unity, this is my tool.

so i headed to Facebook and download the latest SDK for unity and boy did it take me time to figure how it works. after weeks of struggle i found out that the Facebook SDK can not upload video, well at least not yet (i hope i can ask them if they could make it that the Facebook unity SDK can do everything that all the other sdk's can do, like their iOS sdk and android sdk).

the way i found out was when i submitted a bug report and asked a Facebook team member and they told me that it is not supported. i then went to check the references of the Facebook iOS sdk and compared it to the reference of the Facebook unity SDK and to my wonder the calls are not there.

**so my question is how can i use Facebook sdk in unity the way that i want it to?**

is there a method of using the Facebook iOS SDK in unity and not the Facebook unity SDK?

At the end of the day i would really like to push the app out on android as well hence why i added the android tag. so I'm sure if i can achieve it with either platform i can just do it for the other one as well.

please if anyone can share assistance it would be appreciated, I'm extremely serious to get this project completed i can't wait to share my idea with the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like I've confused myself. apparently one can do exactly what i want to do. The Facebook team member responded to my question I've included his exact reply for your convenience.
[image]